# Java-How to calculate accurate time difference while using Joda Time Jar

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm having problem with Joda time jar that I downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/2.2/ . I can get the result when I use the following snippet

```
static void timeDifferencewithJoda()  {

    String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
    String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

        System.out.print(Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays() + " days, ");
        System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24 + " hours, ");
        System.out.print(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60 + " minutes, ");
        System.out.print(Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds() % 60 + " seconds.");

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

The Result was

```
1 days, 1 hours, 1 minutes, 50 seconds.
```

But I face the confliction with this time difference .

```
01/14/2012 09:29:58

01/15/2012 10:31:48
```

here the two time has been declared ,but there's no indication to the period like AM or PM.  ie., The time may be morning or evening .How to I get exact time difference ?

Any help regarding this will be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Using [Joda formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (non AM/PM)**

```
  final String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
  final String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";
  final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  final DateTime dt1 = format.parseDateTime(dateStart);
  final DateTime dt2 = format.parseDateTime(dateStop);

  System.out.print(Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays() + " days, ");
  System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24 + " hours, ");
  System.out.print(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60 + " minutes, ");
  System.out.print(Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds() % 60 + " seconds.");
```

**Using [Joda formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (with AM/PM)**

```
  final String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58 AM";
  final String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48 PM";
  final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
  final DateTime dt1 = format.parseDateTime(dateStart);
  final DateTime dt2 = format.parseDateTime(dateStop);

  System.out.print(Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays() + " days, ");
  System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24 + " hours, ");
  System.out.print(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60 + " minutes, ");
  System.out.print(Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds() % 60 + " seconds.");
```

**Calculate units between with [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)**

```
  final Period period = new Period(dt1, dt2);
  System.out.print(period.getDays() + " days, ");
  System.out.print(period.getHours() + " hours, ");
  System.out.print(period.getMinutes() + " minutes, ");
  System.out.print(period.getSeconds() + " seconds.");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SimpleDateFormat, you have HH to specify hours, and as stated in documentation, HH stands for - Hour in day (0-23). So AM/PM does not apply here. If you want AM/PM hours, you should use KK or hh instead. You can see documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I'm in huge turmoil .can you provide me a sample ?

Comment: You can specify format as `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");`
Then you can enter dates like:
    `String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58 AM";`
    `String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48 PM";`

Comment: sorry :( I did try this. I couldn't get the solution .The solution that Ilya gave is currently working for me... Anyway,thank you for trying to help me :)