# Time difference between two calendar dates

Tags: java

I am looking for to calculate the time difference between two calendar dates and need the result difference in minutes. Below is what I am trying but it says: can't apply - operator. My `page.getLastModified().getTime()` gives me Calendar object. Any idea how can I achieve this.

`long lastModified = page.getLastModified().getTime() - Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTime()` returns `Date` instance and there is no overloaded `-` operator for Date. You may try with `getTimeInMillis()` to get difference milliseconds between two dates. You can later convert these milliseconds to minutes for instance with

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(durationInMillis)
```

Answer (score -1):

I generally make use of

> [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Simply because it has functions to give you the time between two dates.

Read into this previous post [Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499987/java-how-to-calculate-accurate-time-difference-while-using-joda-time-jar) for more info on how to.

Comment: I think it might be better to give a quick example of the method(s) you speak of doing that. It may be better as a comment otherwise; this form is really just "link-only".

Comment: Yes, was working on it. I knew the post about how to already existed here somewhere... TY ! :)

Comment: Java 8 time replaces Joda Time, so I wouldn't recommend it for anything new.