# How to find out if SimpleDateFormat is using seconds or minutes

Tags: java, swing, simpledateformat

I'm making a game with a timer and it tell's you how long you took to complete the game at the end, it's a basic game so some people may beat it in less than a minute so i want to know is there any way to detect if there if the minutes are equal to 00 so then i can set the text to say 00:12 seconds and if it's not equal to 00 then it will say 01:12 Minutes. This is the code that i am using to work out the times.

```
Date start = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
```

And the work out the final time is simply

```
Date now = new Date();
sdf.format(new Date(now.getTime() - start.getTime()))
```

Comment: This question doesn't *really* have anything to do with `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: What is it to do with then? I'm new btw

Comment: Fixed it just had to do some expanding.

Comment: If you fixed it, would you be able to post your answer? For the next person perhaps.

Comment: already have. Just gotta wait 2 days to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it.

```
Date start = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdfm = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
SimpleDateFormat sdfs = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");

Date now = new Date();

if(sdfm.format(new Date(now.getTime() - start.getTime())).equals("00")){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Won!! It only took you " + sdfs.format(new Date(now.getTime() - start.getTime())) + " Seconds", "You Won!!", 1);
    }else{  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Won!! It only took you " + sdfm.format(new Date(now.getTime() - start.getTime())) +  ":" + sdfs.format(new Date(now.getTime() - start.getTime())) + " Minutes", "You Won!!", 1);
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

/*
 * Your code
 */

long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

long seconds = (diff / 1000) % 60;
long minutes = (diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long hours = (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

System.out.println("Total " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds");
```

Refer below links for another possible solutions,

[Java-How to calculate accurate time difference while using Joda Time Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499987/java-how-to-calculate-accurate-time-difference-while-using-joda-time-jar)

[How can I calculate a time span in Java and format the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635935/how-can-i-calculate-a-time-span-in-java-and-format-the-output)